Laravel 11 is not displaying images on cPanel
In the live server, my Laravel project is not displaying images. The symbolic link has been created correctly, and images are successfully uploaded to storage/app/public/images. However, images are only displayed if they are moved to storage/images. Can you please help me resolve this issue?
tring get image from storage->app ->public ->images

How do you display the images in your code? If you store an image in storage/app/public/images the symlink will  make it available on /storage/images.
the symlink is storage -> storage/app/public

Can we get a [mcve] please?

I don't know it upload successfully to storage/app/public/ but when we access by asset(url)) not show, it's link correctly show from public/storage to storage/app/public/ but if we create new folder by the name of images in storage. But if we move images folder from public back to storage its image accessible

I assume that in the .env file specify the correct disk. Maybe you have a local disk
FILESYSTEM_DISK=public

Also check if the link is correct
APP_URL=


This writed correctly FILESYSTEM_DISK=public
